# Example of a random variable for which $\|\mathbb{E}[x]\| <\infty$ but $\mathbb{E}[\|x\|]=\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, jensen-inequality

We know by Jensen's inequality and the convexity of the euclidean norm that,

$$\mathbb{E}[\|x\|]\geq\|\mathbb{E}[x]\|$$

I wonder, then, if it's possible to have a random variable $x$ whose expected norm is finite but the norm of the expectation is infinite?

Comment: your claim is not possible by the very definition of expectation. If $X$ has finite expectation, then both $X^+ = max(X, 0)$ and $X^- = min(X, 0 )$ have finite expectations (notice that they do not have sign change) and then $\mathbb{E} (X) $ is defined as the sum of $\mathbb{E}{X^+}$ and $\mathbb{E}{X^-}$. Thus $\mathbb{E}(|X|) $ becomes finite. To put it short, the integrals here are understood in Lebesgue sense hence something is integrable if it is with absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

"I  wonder, then, if it's possible to have a random variable $x$ whose expected norm is finite but the norm of the expectation is infinite?": The inequality you cite says precisely that this is impossible.

The sensible question is the other way around. In fact,  by the standard definitions, if  $\Bbb E[||x||]=\infty$ then $\Bbb E[x]$ is undefined, so the question of whether it can have finite norm is meaningless.